# How to get current year first date in iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios7

Am working in iphone application, Now i want to get current year and current month first date from current date. 
    **For (e.x: First date of year : 2013/01/01)
    And (e.x first date of month is: 2013/12/01)**

Please help me to out of this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
// This is your currentDate
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

// NSDateFormatter to separate the Year and Month from currentDate
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

NSInteger currentYear = [[df stringFromDate:today] integerValue];
NSString *currentYearFirstDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/01/01", currentYear];

[df setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSInteger currentMonth = [[df stringFromDate:today] integerValue];
NSString *currentMonthFirstDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d/01", currentYear, currentMonth];

// You can get date object from above string via using below date format
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setDay:1];
self.currentDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
int m = components.month;
int y = components.year;
int d = components.day;

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy MM dd"];
NSDate *firstDateOfMonth = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d 01",y,m]];
NSDate *firstDateOfYear = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d 01 01",y]];
```

Comment: Well `%@` is for object type while **m**, **y** and **d** all are integers. So replace `%@` with `%d`.

Comment: @user1547937 Because units is not defined in this example. You should use units according to you.